# How is difficulty calculated and what does each difficulty rating mean?

Tags: smite

In Smite each god has a difficulty rating.

How is this calculated?  Is it dynamically adjusted or "hard-coded" to a specific setting?

What does it mean for a god to be "easy" or "hard"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a subjective indication of difficulty by the developers of the game. They are letting you as a player know what you're getting yourself into by playing the god. Generally, gods with straightforward abilities will be rated "easy", while gods with abilities that are more situational or require greater player skill to fully maximize may be rated "hard".

Take it with a grain of salt. Your perception of what's difficult or not may differ from the developers' opinion on the matter. The best thing to do is give each god a try and remember which you liked and which you didn't.

Comment: I presume these ratings reflect a traditional conquest game rather than arena?

Comment: @camelCase They're kind of independent of such things. The character's abilities remain the same through modes, and a character with a tricky skill shot like Hou Yi is still going to have a tricky skill shot in arena.

Comment: @StrixVaria: If anything, it's even more tricky because there are way less walls to bounce the shot off of.